# Add text containing slashes at end of specific line in a file using sed

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I want to start mongod with dbpath option as below

```
mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo/ --config /etc/mongod.conf --replSet rs0
```

Here is the mongod.service:-

```
[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
```

How to add `--dbpath and --replSet` option in `ExecStart` on `mongod.service` file using shell script.

I want my output look like below:-

mongod.service:-

```
[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS --dbpath /var/lib/mongo/ --config /etc/mongod.conf --replSet rs0
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
```

I know to add some text at the end of line using below command:

```
sed '/ExecStart/s/$/ test/' mongod.service
```

Don't know how to add what I mentioned above as it contains hyphen, slash, etc.

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: I know to add some text at the end of line like "sed '/ExecStart/s/$/ test/' mongod.service " . Don't know how to add what I mentioned above as it contains hyphen, slash, etc.

Comment: Add it to the question! @karan

Comment: Updated  the question

Comment: Since the service `$OPTIONS` already contains the path to a config file (`/etc/mongod.conf`), a more correct way to approach your changes would be to set the [`storage.dbPath`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath) and [`replication.replSetName`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#replication.replSetName) values in the `/etc/mongod.conf` config file. Any manual changes to the `mongod.service` file may not be preserved between upgrades or reinstalls; the config file will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of using `sed` is right, but since the replace part contains `/` it should be escaped or separate separators need to be used for `sed`. Also double-quoting the `sed` expression would allow you to easily preserve the spaces. But need to ensure there is no `$` expressions in the replace path.

```
sed "/^ExecStart=/s/$/ --dbpath \/var\/lib\/mongo\/ --config \/etc\/mongod.conf --replSet rs0/" file
```

Also could be done with `awk` by incrementing a column count by 1 and filling this in the last column

```
awk -F= '$1=="ExecStart"{NF++; $NF="--dbpath /var/lib/mongo/ --config /etc/mongod.conf --replSet rs0"}1' file
```